# Creating multiple Variables with the same function but with different parameters

Tags: python, function, variables, parameters

I'm new to python and I was doing some challenges .. one challenge is to take a set of ascii characters and then separate them then reorganize them to make distinct letters that you can call individually (t).. I managed to separate the letters and reassemble them but I'm now trying to make them more readable (make each letter represent itself instead of (lettercreator(num)) .. there is a long way which is to name each letter and assign each value individually .. but is there any other way ? .. the way i tried below is wrong but its just to show what I'm trying to do.
here is the ascii if anyone's interested

```
 #  ##   ## ##  ### ###  ## # # ###  ## # # #   # # ###  #  ##   #  ##   ## ### # # # # # # # # # # ### ### 
# # # # #   # # #   #   #   # #  #    # # # #   ### # # # # # # # # # # #    #  # # # # # # # # # #   #   # 
### ##  #   # # ##  ##  # # ###  #    # ##  #   ### # # # # ##  # # ##   #   #  # # # # ###  #   #   #   ## 
# # # # #   # # #   #   # # # #  #  # # # # #   # # # # # # #    ## # #   #  #  # # # # ### # #  #  #       
# # ##   ## ##  ### #    ## # # ###  #  # # ### # # # #  #  #     # # # ##   #  ###  #  # # # #  #  ###  #  
l = int(input())
h = int(input())
t = input()
y=[]
for i in range(h):
    row = input()
    y.append([row[i:i+l] for i in range(0, len(row), l)])
def lettercreator(da):
        for u in range(h):
            print((y[u][da]))
        return 0
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z=lettercreator(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionaries with a one line for loop-

```
lettercreator_output = {chr(i+97):lettercreator(i) for i in range(26)}
```

When you want to access the variables, use `lettercreator_output['a']` instead of just `a`